# Can't find a memory leak in my code

Tags: java

I have the following method that makes a HTTP Get request on a server an parses the response as Java source code. I'm doing this for multiple files in the same time. This works quite well for the first few files, but after a certain amount of time I get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

The exception is thrown in the line: `jp.parse(new StringReader(responseString));` I think the problem is a memory leak, because the file I'm trying to parse there isn't really big. Only a few dozen lines of code. But I can't find the cause for this exception. Any hints?

```
public void retrieveSourceCode() {
            try {
                System.out.println("Try to get: " + getSourceCodeURI());
                String responseString = RestServices.getInstance().sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getSourceCodeURI());
                JavaSourceFactory jsf = new JavaSourceFactory();
                JavaParser jp = new JavaParser(jsf);
                jp.parse(new StringReader(responseString));
                Iterator<?> iterator = jsf.getJavaSources();
                while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                    JavaSource source =  ((JavaSource) iterator.next());
                    fileName = source.getQName().toString();
                    sourceCode = source.toString();
                }
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                fileName = "no file name";
                sourceCode = "no sourcecode available";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                fileName = "no file name";
                sourceCode = "no sourcecode available";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (RestServicesException e) {
                fileName = "no file name";
                sourceCode = "no sourcecode available";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (RecognitionException e) {
                fileName = "no file name";
                sourceCode = "no sourcecode available";
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TokenStreamException e) {
                fileName = "no file name";
                sourceCode = "no sourcecode available";
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (before == null) {
                beforeSourceCode = "no before sourcecode available";
            } else {
                try {
                    String responseString = RestServices.getInstance().sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getBeforeVersionURI());
                    JavaSourceFactory jsf = new JavaSourceFactory();
                    JavaParser jp = new JavaParser(jsf);
                    jp.parse(new StringReader(responseString));
                    Iterator<?> iterator = jsf.getJavaSources();
                    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                        JavaSource source = (JavaSource) iterator.next();
                        beforeSourceCode = source.toString();
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    beforeSourceCode = "no before sourcecode available";
                } catch (RecognitionException e) {
                    beforeSourceCode = "no before sourcecode available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TokenStreamException e) {
                    beforeSourceCode = "no before sourcecode available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    beforeSourceCode = "no before sourcecode available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RestServicesException e) {
                    beforeSourceCode = "no before sourcecode available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            if (after == null) {
                afterSourceCode = "no after sourcecode available";
            } else {
                try {
                    String responseString = RestServices.getInstance().sendGetRequestJsonTextToString(getAfterVersionURI());
                    JavaSourceFactory jsf = new JavaSourceFactory();
                    JavaParser jp = new JavaParser(jsf);
                    jp.parse(new StringReader(responseString));
                    Iterator<?> iterator = jsf.getJavaSources();
                    while(iterator.hasNext()) {
                        JavaSource source = (JavaSource) iterator.next();
                        afterSourceCode = source.toString();
                    }
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    afterSourceCode = "no after sourcecode available";
                } catch (RecognitionException e) {
                    afterSourceCode = "no after sourcecode available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (TokenStreamException e) {
                    afterSourceCode = "no after sourcecode available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    afterSourceCode = "no after sourcecode available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (RestServicesException e) {
                    afterSourceCode = "no after sourcecode available";
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            getChangeSet().addAffectedFile(getFileName());
    }
```

Comment: Why not use a memory profiler and see what's using the memory?

Comment: Did you create a memory dump and analyze that?

Comment: I use YourKit, and love it (no connection other than as a customer): http://www.yourkit.com/

Comment: Why in the while loop the sourceCode variable is overwritten multiple times?

Comment: jProfiler and YourKit are both awesome profilers, and you can try them out for free. Also, make sure you're closing your readers, that might be where the memory is getting caught up.

Comment: @pcalcao I runned a profiler and found that the class char[] is consuming almost 3 gb of memory at peak times. So I assume someone char[] objects are generated. But I can't find it in my code.

Comment: Hard to say for sure without a good look at the profiler, but my guess is that it's the StringReader building those char[], like I said before, be sure to close them after they're no longer needed so the Garbage collector can handle them. Is that parse method cleaning up all resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does `getChangeSet().addAffectedFile()` do? You might want to use a profiler as already suggested?

Is it holding on to things? Also, you might want to split that method up into pieces.

Comment: This just adds the passed string to an arraylist.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, it accumulates more and more data after every request. That sounds like the source of your memory leak.

Comment: I don't think so. I printed out the number of elements there and it is under 100.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you keep repeating those catch blocks with the same handling code inside?  I'd catch Exception once and be done with it.  The rest of them do nothing but add visual clutter.

But that's not an answer to your question....

Are those classes yours, or are they from a library?  I'm guessing that it's the [Apache JAXMe](http://ws.apache.org/jaxme/js/jparser.html) library.

If you're using a Sun JVM, you can download [Visual VM 1.3.3](http://visualvm.java.net/), install all the plugins, open it up, and start your process to see what's going on.  It'll show you memory by generation, CPU, threads etc.  It's a great tool.

Why don't you try adding a finally block and clear the array?  You don't keep that data between calls, do you?  If yes, how do other callers look up and use the outcome?  Maybe a WeakHashMap could be your solution.  You'll give the JVM a chance to clean up if it needs to.

You should be careful about thread safety.  Servlets are shared, so if you're hanging onto that mutable object you need worry about synchronization.

Comment: Yes that should be refactored into one try/catch block. That are mine classes.

Comment: Which array are you talking about?

Comment: The one that you printed out the number of elements for.  I guessed that you meant a local variable.